# How to export Google Alerts citations?

Tags: email, web, html, thunderbird, google

I have several months of Google Alerts in my email and I would like to share them somewhere on the web (for instance on a MediaWiki wiki). Is there an easy way to export them?

The alerts contain HTML of this kind (seen from Thunderbird):

```
<div style="color:#fff;font-size:9px;letter-spacing:0.8px"> <div style="padding:3px 0px 4px 4px;background:rgb(255,255,255);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);width:96px">La Provincia di Biella</div> </div> <!--[if gte mso 9]></div><![endif]--> </td> </tr> </table> </a> <div>  <span style="padding:0px 6px 0px 0px"> <a href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&amp;sa=t&amp;url=http://www.laprovinciadibiella.it/web/castelletto-cervo-nei-siti-cluniacensi-9458&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAEYACoTMzc2NjcxMzA4NDYzNjc4NjUwMjIZZThjOGE1NjBlZjA5ZDRkMDppdDppdDpJVA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEW4QKACEvE_AbGrMGOBJ2y4dFSIw" style="color:#427fed;display:inline;text-decoration:none;font-size:16px;line-height:20px">Castelletto Cervo nei siti cluniacensi</a> </span>  <div> <div style="padding:2px 0px 8px 0px"> <div style="color:#737373;font-size:12px"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#737373">La Provincia di Biella</a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [worked for me](https://it.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Rassegna_stampa/Smistamento&oldid=76093598):

1. download the alerts from your email in a Thunderbird directory;
2. install the ImportExportTools plugin and export the whole directory as HTML;
3. go to the export directory and run: `find * -print0 | xargs -0 -I § bash -c 'NAME="§"; DATE="{{#time:j F Y| ${NAME:0:8} }}"; grep --text -Eo "ru=([^&]+)&amp;" "§" | sed "s,ru=,;$DATE:,g" | sed "s,&amp;,,g" ; ' | sort -ru`

I used `;$DATE:` as prefix for each URL because that's meaningful wikitext and [parser functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Parser_functions) allow to easily translate the "AAAAMMDD" format used by the export files. You can replace with anything.

A smarter version may send the URL to Zotero or Citoid to get a proper citation, or maybe parse the original HTML to extract more information. The HTML format seems to be different for alerts before 2014-01-18.

Tested with GNU findutils 4.5.12, bash 4.3.42.

TODO: download the "see more articles" links and parse those too. In busy days, the emails only contain a random selection of the "top" news.